# Load more list items using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have list that everytime I click on a button it loads more items of the list, but when I use a loop to get a list from an array, the code doesn't work!

```
.hideclass { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: none;

}


<ul></ul>

<div id="loadmore">MORE</div>




const array = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']


const list = document.querySelector('ul'),
    items  = list.querySelectorAll('li'),
    buttonloadmore =  document.querySelector('#loadmore'),
    maxItems = 10,
    hideclass = "hideclass";


//Generate liste
output = ''
array.forEach(item => {
  output += `<li class="item"> </li>`;          
})

list.innerHTML = output;




[].forEach.call(items, (item, index) => {
    if (index > maxItems - 1) {
        item.classList.add(hideclass);
    }
});



buttonloadmore.addEventListener('click', () => {

  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.' + hideclass), (item, index) => {

      if (index < maxItems - 1) {
          item.classList.remove(hideclass);
      }

      if ( document.querySelectorAll('.' + hideclass).length === 0) {
          buttonloadmore.style.display = 'none';
      }

  });

});
```

Working example without array [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdxxcode/8euoykz3/)

Is there any way to work with dynamic lists? or use the button to limit the `forEach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns an arraylike of Nodes that are in the document *by the time you call it*. I  your case, you query for `<li>`s, but as no `<li>` was added yet you don't find anything, the `items` arraylike is therefore empty. Then you add some `<li>`s but `items` will stay empty.

You should query for the Nodes after you've added them.